# How to import .lib into .dll?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I'm trying to code a dll as a plugin for some system using C++. This plugin will make use of another library which is a .lib file and should output only one .dll file as a result. So I want this other .lib file included in my dll. There should be only one dll file and lib file should be included in it, so that I could include this dll file into the system as a one-file plugin. Is this possible and how?

I'm using Visual C++ 2010 Express.

Thank you.

Comment: I edited the question a bit. What I want is just a dll file that includes the lib. I will import that dll file into the other system as a plugin. I try to link it in, but the resulting dll file doesn't seem to include lib. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the VS linker doesn't have an option equivalent to `ld`'s [`--whole-archive`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ld) which can be used to include an entire library.

Your best bet is to unpack the library and link in the resulting object files. You can use the librarian (`lib` tool) for that. To list all members of the library, use [`lib /LIST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e17b885t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Object files have to be extracted one by one, using [`lib /EXTRACT:member`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/889z8z58%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).